# Android Studio: How do I disable reformat code completion popup

Tags: android-studio

I'm developing an app on my mac in Android Studio. When I reformat code an annoying popup appears telling me how many lines have been formatted, etc. Is there a way to disable this popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences > Editor > General

The first option under the "Formatting" header is "Show notification after reformat code action"; disable it.